# How to see only my git files in my new branch?

Tags: git

After working in a new git feature branch, I would like to see the files I have changed in the new branch. So I try this:

```
  git log --author=myname master...
```

and then for each of the commits I do

```
  git diff --name-only <commit>
```

and this often works if the branch is new enough.

However, eventually, the latter command starts taking a long time, possibly because I have done a

```
    git pull
```

or maybe

```
    git pull origin master
```

Sometimes the "git diff --name-only " takes 40 minutes! And then it is useless because there are so many files I cannot easily find me.

So then I try

```
 git diff --name-only $(git merge-base -a master HEAD) HEAD
```

and if the branch is new enough, it works, otherwise it takes a long time and I get a acres of files that I don't recognize.

However, when I do a push followed by pull request, I see that the server is able to figure out all the files in all the commits that need to be reviewed and I don't see those acres of other files that result from the "git pull". Sometimes doing "git commit --amend" helps but I really need to see the list of files I am working on.

Question: how can I write a script to do what the pull request does (with the code review feature) so I can ignore all those other changes from "git pull" and just see my files names (and optionally my changes).

Basically, I would like to perform my own private code review before doing a commit. I was reprimanded recently because I did lots of commit/pushes that had similar titles such as "tidy up code" so I could see my changes in the pull request web site (and I did not want to squash my changes incase I needed to cherry pick certain commits later).

Could rebasing help me? I tried that and got lots of merge conflicts and determined from google searching that this is a common peril of rebasing.

Thanks

Siegfried